# Checking if IDs in array are not null and adding them into new array

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, array

My view object:

```
{
    description: "2tik 2tags"
    id: 100
    portfolio: "TSLA"
    term_id_1: 260751
    term_id_2: 285493
    term_id_3: null
    ticker_1: "GOOG"
    ticker_2: "TSLA"
    ticker_3: ""
    timespan: "ld"
    top: ""
}
```

I need to grab the `term_id`s and stick them into a new array, but only if they are not `null`.

What I'm currently using:

```
function reSelectTags(view) {
    console.log('view',view);
    // Seperate term_ids:
    var term_ids = [];

    if (view.term_id_1 != null) {
        term_ids.push(view.term_id_1);
    }

    if (view.term_id_2 != null) {
        term_ids.push(view.term_id_2);
    }

    if (view.term_id_3 != null) {
        term_ids.push(view.term_id_3);
    }

    console.log('term_ids',term_ids);
}
```

This gets the job done, but I'm wondering if there is a better, cleaner way, perhaps on 1 or 2 lines that could accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the property names are sequential, you can just put it into a `for` loop:

```
function reSelectTags(view) {
    var val, term_ids = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        val = view["term_id_" + i];
        if (val != null) {
            term_ids.push(val);
        }
    }
    console.log(term_ids);
}
```

You can also just put repeated code into a local function:

```
function reSelectTags(view) {
    var term_ids = [];

    function pushVal(name) {
        if (view[name] != null) {
            term_ids.push(view[name]);
        }
    }
    pushVal("term_id_1");
    pushVal("term_id_2");
    pushVal("term_id_3");
    console.log(term_ids);
}
```